# Getting "Ambiguous use of 'MYFUNCTION()'" error when running XCTests

Tags: arrays, swift, xctest

I'm getting an error for several functions when trying to run XCTests.

For example, I have a simple extension for arrays to distill a unique Array:

```
public extension CollectionType where Generator.Element: Hashable {
    /// Returns the collection with duplicate values in `self` removed.
    var unique: [Generator.Element] {
        get {
            var seen: [Generator.Element:Bool] = [:]
            return self.filter { (element) -> Bool in
                return seen.updateValue(true, forKey: element) == nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in the tests, I'm getting an error when I try to use it:

```
Ambiguous use of 'unique'
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

I figured out my problem was that I had my swift file included in both my framework target as well as the XCTest target (hence the compiler saw the file included twice causing the ambiguity).  Removing it from the Test target fixed the error.  Hopefully this will help someone else (or my future self).

Comment: Yes, keep production code in your production target. Keep test code in your test target. Don't let them mix.